# Intercept in the ARProcess

Tags: functions, time-series

In the [`ARProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ARProcess.html) help file I don't understand whether an intercept is included or not. How would I add one? I am using version 9 of *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with AR processes, but I suspect that you might be looking for the following syntax:

```
ARProcess[c, {a1, ... , ap}, v]
```

which, according to the documentation, represents an AR process with a "constant" $c$, which I think is the same as the intercept you are looking for.

For instance, compare the following:

```
(* Intercept value = 2 *)
DateListPlot@RandomFunction[ARProcess[2, {0.1, -0.1}, 1*^-6], {1, 10^2}]
```

[image: int2]

```
(* Intercept value = 0 *)
DateListPlot@RandomFunction[ARProcess[0, {0.1, -0.1}, 1*^-6], {1, 10^2}]
```

[image: int0]

Comment: Marco, but in Version 9 that option is not available...

Comment: I'm afraid specifying a nonzero mean `c` like this was not possible in _Mathematica_ 9, but was added in _Mathematica_ 10.